# Live data updates (vehicle tracking)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, real-time, tracking

I am developing a system for live/real time vehicle tracking. 
My system has two parts. A web part and an Android application part. 
The Android application just sends the latitude and longitude coordinates with a specific vehicle name successfully to a server.

In the web part I was able to draw a polyline using the values from database, but i can not show the latest/updated position of my vehicle. My system requires a reload/refresh of the page to get the latest values from the database.

I want to do that without refreshing. It should be updated automatically in the browser.

I am using php, mySQL and javascript till now. I do not want to use ajax.

Comment: http://traintimes.org.uk/map/tube/
i want to do something like that.

Comment: If you want to do _that_ -- Ajax is your friend.

Comment: Thanks Mr David. But can not i simply do it by javascript?

Comment: You also stated that you want to update your data (map) without refreshing -- this is the essence of Ajax.

Comment: Actually i learned a little at the Google map API documentation. And that contains very little knowledge of javascript/ ajax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For these type of application (Nodejs + Socket listener) is a best combination ,bcoz for this your server will receive a concurrent requests which will require a  small computation.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18664857/2557900

Comment: Ok. i am checking these. :)  Thanks.