# NodeJS servers requests

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

I'm working with NodeJS and I'm still familiarizing with it.

Given the structure of my system I have two NodeJS servers running in different machines.
The user/browser sends a request to the first server, which returns to the browser a JSON file that is located in this first machine.

This first server also updates this JSON file every 5-10 seconds sending a request to the second server, which returns another JSON file which data will overwrite the one in the JSON file in the first server, so the next user/browser request will be updated.
This second server also has a NodeJS server running but it only dispatches the request coming from the first server.

I have this structure since I don't want the user to know about the second server for security reasons (Anyone could see the redirection with any dev tools).

This two events are executed asynchronously since the Browser petitions may be in different time from the event updating the JSON file.

My question is: How can I update the JSON file in the first server? I wonder if there's a NodeJS library I can use for requesting the new JSON file to the second server.

I make the Browser-FirstServer petition via AJAX and everything works properly, but AJAX only works on the client side, so I'm not really sure how to do this for the First-Second server request.

Any help would be appreciated.

Something i'm xpecting for is the following:

```
setInterval(function(){ 
// make request to server 2

//receive JSON file

// use 'fs' for overwriting the JSON from server 1

}, 5000)
```

Comment: Have you looked at http://nodejs.org/api/http.html ?

Comment: Looks like you want a simple caching proxy server.

Comment: I still don't have any code about handling the updating since I don't exactly know how to ask for the JSON from the server 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use the built in [http](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html)/[https](http://nodejs.org/api/https.html) modules in nodejs or use something like [request](https://www.npmjs.org/package/request)

```
var request = require('request');
request('/url/for/json', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    //write body to the file system
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of operating both as web (html) servers, I strongly advise connecting to the 2nd using sockets... This way you can pass information/changes back and forth whenever an event happens. [Here's an example of using sockets in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664530/how-to-create-a-simple-socket-in-node-js)