# Node JS/ Socket.IO - Receive only over TCP/IP

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, windows-ce, tcp

What I have is some very old devices that use Windows CE. The built in application to these devices can transmit out a string via a port TCP/IP which I would like to be able to listen to on a webpage and display.

I am in the process of learning Node.Js and came across the Sockets.IO lesson and got excited at the prospect of being able to listen on the port for the IP address and all of our problems would be solved! However...a co-worker has informed me that he went down this road previously and since everything in node is HTTP and our devices would have no idea what to do with the HTTP requests that I am barking up the wrong tree (some pun intended).

So my question - is there a way using some part of Node.JS to simply create a listener - plug in the IP Address and the port number on my device and absorb what it is sending?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Sure, node can bind to a port and act as a server, which is how it does HTTP and sockets. You can use it as a server for your own protocol, although node really isn't good at handling binary data.

Comment: So even if my CE device does not understand HTTP Requests, Node can bind to that IP/Port and receive what it gives? The output from the CE device is a specially formatted string which I will need to parse out...but getting the string is the most important thing to me.

Comment: The [`net` module](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html) is a generic TCP server. The HTTP servers are build on top of that.

Comment: Forgive me, as all of this is very new to me (yay learning!) - so do I need to use the Socket.IO package then to accomplish this?

Comment: @PWilliams0530 No, I don't think anyone here has suggested Socket.io. (Careful not to confuse the software library called "Socket.io" with the [networking concept of a socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket).)

Comment: @apsillers: the lightbulb of possibility for me went off when I was going through the Socket.io module of my Node.js course I am going through at the moment which is where I thought they were related.

Everything I am seeing is showing server/client side code - which I faintly understand. What I am in need of is the proper tools to use in order to create a listener on node, connect it to the IP/Port of my device and get what it is giving me (a string).

Comment: @PWilliams0530 I think that's what's in the answer for the [link I suiggested](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664530/how-to-create-a-simple-socket-in-node-js). You already have a client, right? You don't need to write a client. You need to stand up a server (using the `net` module, as demonstrated in that answer) listening on some port, and then point the client at the server's address/port so it can connect.

Comment: @apsillers: Doing some more reading - I am not actually sure node.js offers me the solution I am seeking. My goal was to, using only javascript and straight from a browser, listen to this IP/Port and get the string it was sending out.

Comment: @PWilliams0530 Wait, I think I had a fundamental misunderstanding here. The Windows CE device you have is acting as a ***server*** -- is that right? That is, they will respond with their string to anything that sends a request, without a human manually doing anything on the CE device. Then you already have a server, and you need to use the client code included in that same link. Your browser can only communicate with HTTP and WebSocket servers, so you need to have the browser contact a web server, then the web server acts as a client to the CE device and sends the response back to the browser.